# Perform an update query that sets True if condition and False if not condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to write a stored procedure, which is giving me customers back, which fall into a specific segment, because of their buying behaviour of a specific timeframe.

For these customers the segment field will be set to true, the ones, which are not coming out of the given query need to be set to false, if their segment was true.

I have a problem on the procedure itself, with the return type I think, can someone help with that.

Is it possible to set values that are not coming out of the query to the value FALSE, without working with a temporal table?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION segment_men1() AS

RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
FOR r IN
SELECT AD.id FROM account AD
    INNER JOIN transactions TRA ON TRA.customerID = AD.id
        WHERE AD.gender = "male"
        AND TRA.transactionDate >= current_date - interval "365" days;

    LOOP
        UPDATE account
        SET Segment_Men = true
        WHERE NEXT r;

    END LOOP;
RETURN;

END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

Why would you be using a loop for this?  Just do the update directly:

```
UPDATE account AD
    SET Segment_Men = true
    FROM transactions TRA 
    WHERE TRA.customerID = AD.id AND
          AD.gender = 'male' AND
          TRA.transactionDate >= current_date - interval '365' days;
```

Comment: And then a negative check to set  = False.

Comment: Thanks for this! and also the previous comment. This is much more convenient

Comment: @user1694674 . . . The simplest method might be to set all the values to `false` before running this `update`.  Handling a `left join` in the `update` gets a little complicated in Postgres.